# ActionBar Sherlock build issues in maven

Tags: java, android, maven, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

Hi i am trying to build an android project that uses actionbarsherlock and holoeverywhere but everytime i build via mvn install i get the follow error:

```
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/res/values/attrs.xml:11: error: Attribute "buttonBarButtonStyle" has already been defined
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:214: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:258: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values/abs__styles.xml:309: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[INFO] /Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.

[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:493)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd "/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello" && /Users/Jonathan/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/18.0.0/aapt package -m -J '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/generated-sources/r' -M '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/AndroidManifest.xml' -S '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/res' -S '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/jr.sample.hellolibrary_HelloLibrary_apklib_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/res' -S '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/org.holoeverywhere_slidingmenu_apklib_1.4.2/res' -S '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/org.holoeverywhere_library_apklib_1.6.8/res' -S '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/target/unpack/apklibs/com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.4.0/res' --auto-add-overlay -A '/Users/Jonathan/Android work/Hello/assets' -I /Users/Jonathan/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-8/android.jar, Result = 1
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:246)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:489)
    ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -
```

---

Complains it cant find various styles from the res.

Here is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.exmaple.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hello</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Hello</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Make sure this is below the android dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
            <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jr.sample.hellolibrary</groupId>
            <artifactId>HelloLibrary</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.holoeverywhere</groupId>
            <artifactId>slidingmenu</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.activeandroid</groupId>
            <artifactId>activeandroid</artifactId>
            <version>3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.holoeverywhere</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nineoldandroids</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <!-- platform or api level (api level 16 = platform 4.1) -->
                        <platform>8</platform>
                        <path>/Users/Jonathan/android-sdk-macosx</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>allow-snapshots</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```